# Is GCC correct to warn of format string mismatch with a scoped enum?

Tags: c++, enums, gcc-warning, enum-class

When using a scoped enum in a varargs context, it is defined to be passed as its underlying type, as answered in "[Can I use enum class values as arguments to varargs functions?](/q/7786787)"  As I understand it, this is the only circumstance in which a scoped enum will be converted implicitly, like an unscoped enum is.

Consider this program:

```
enum Foo : char { F };
enum class Bar : char { B };

#include <cstdio>
int main()
{
    return !std::printf("%c\n", Foo::F)
        +  !std::printf("%c\n", Bar::B);
}
```

The compiler (`g++` version 6.3.0) is happy with the first print, of a `Foo`, but complains when I pass a `Bar`:

```
0.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
0.cpp:10:34: warning: format ‘%c’ expects argument of type ‘int’, but argument 2 has type ‘Bar’ [-Wformat=]
         +  !printf("%c\n", Bar::B);
                                  ^
```

`g++` version 4.8.2 didn't complain about this, but `g++` 6.3.0 does (and that's why it now concerns me).  Both versions complain about the first print when there is a substantive mismatch, such as using `%f` or `%s`, or if I change `Foo` to use a `long` underlying type; that's why I enable `-Wformat`.

I understand that warnings are not a standards-conformance issue, and I know how to change my code to address these (e.g. using the functions in answers to [How can I output the value of an enum class in C++11?](/q/11421432)), but I also believe that warnings are unhelpful if they produce false positives.  Is there any potential for actual harm in passing a scoped enum to a formatted I/O function when the underlying type of the enum matches the corresponding conversion specification in the format string?

Comment: GCC version 4.8 probably didn't complain because it didn't have a full C++11 implementation, and scoped enumerations was introduced in C++11.

Comment: See the accepted answer from the question you linked: Unscoped enum values are integer promoted, but scoped enums (the `enum class` ones) are not.

Comment: @cpplearner Even if I change `Bar` to be `enum class : int`, it complains of mismatch, so that's only part of the answer.

Comment: @Toby no it's not: `enum class` signifies a new type without implicit conversions to `int` or the underlying type or whatever, these conversions still apply to plain `enum`.

Comment: @rubenvb, If there are no conversions, then that means that a scoped int passed through varargs can only be used if the `va_arg()` call uses exactly the same type?  I think I understand now.  Thanks to all who commented and answered!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From [this scoped enumeration reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/enum#Scoped_enumerations):

> There are ***no*** implicit conversions from the values of a scoped enumerator to integral types, ...

<sub>[Emphasis mine]</sub>

That means no matter the base type, a scoped enumeration will not be implicitly converted to an `int` (or any other integer type). You must explicitly do the conversion, with e.g. `static_cast` (continued from previous quote):

> ... although `static_cast` may be used to obtain the numeric value of the enumerator.

---

Also, from [this variadic argument reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/variadic_arguments):

> `bool`, `char`, `short`, and ***unscoped*** enumerations are converted to `int` or wider integer types as in integer promotion

<sub>[Again emphasis mine]</sub>

---

And to answer your question if GCC is right in warning you: Yes it is right. What you're doing is not correct.